# Windows 8.1 double cpu usage and very slow

Tags: performance, windows-8.1

I have several computers of identical spec (1.9Ghz i5 scaled to 1.3, 8gb ram, 256gb ssd) running windows 8.1 (installed directly from an 8.1 cd, not upgraded) but since yesterday one has been very slow and unresponsive. According to task manager the cpu usage (when idle) is running at about 35%.

Upon looking at task managers processes pane and sorting by cpu i find that "Desktop Window Manager" is spending the most cpu at around 15% followed by teamviewer with about 12%. When I compare this to one of the working systems i get a cpu usage of about 7% for the "Desktop Window Manager" and a similar percentage for teamviewer which is almost exactly half.

I've looked at several threads and questions such as [Root cause for high CPU usage; which measurement to trust more: Windows Task Manager or Process Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/674999/root-cause-for-high-cpu-usage-which-measurement-to-trust-more-windows-task-man?rq=1) and [Windows 8.1 Pro - CPU Usage Stays at 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/695890/windows-8-1-pro-cpu-usage-stays-at-100) but their solutions haven't helped and I'm out of ideas.

What should i try next?

Comment: Have you tried using a restoration point?

Comment: Not yet. Just going to look at that now. Thanks for the thought

Comment: give me the xperf trace: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD and I can tell you why DWM uses 15% of the CPU.